# How to align bottom a PdfPCell spaning across more than one page?

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp version 4.1.6.16. I have a `PdfPTable` with two columns (1 row).

There is a lot of content in right cell so it spans across whole page and reaches next page.

In the left cell I only want to put some small `PdfPTable` at its bottom. To do it I use `cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;` on the left cell of topmost table. This works well if the row is not bigger than a page.

If the row reaches next page, then the content of the left cell is indeed aligned to bottom, but to **bottom of first page**. So the right cell's content still continues on the next page, but the left cell is empty there (I tested with background color that it spans to next page also).

I tried setting `KeepTogether` on the inner table but it doesn't have any effect. I also thought about doing it with `CellEvent` but I couldn't find so far how to position `IElement` (not only `Image` or text) absolutely in the cell.

Is it a bug or designed behavior, that the content is aligned to the bottom of the first page the cell occupies? Is there a workaround or some better way to put content at the bottom of the cell no matter where it ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally solved the issue with following workaround.

I created a `CellEvent` that gets `PdfPTable` and shifts it upwards as much as its content takes:

```
class BottomFix : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    private readonly PdfPTable _content;

    public BottomFix(PdfPTable content)
    {
        _content = content;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        _content?.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, position.Left, position.Top + _content.TotalHeight, canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS]);
    }
}
```

Then to my original two-row table I added second row, and I add there a cell of height equal to 0, where instead of putting content into, I use this `CellEvent`. The original left cell is left empty, so the content of next row is pushed onto it and it looks as it was originally there. I don't have borders in this table so they are not an issue, but it can also be solved by setting border of this 1px cell to none.

```
var cell = new PdfPCell();
var table = new PdfPTable(1) { /* some content etc... */ };
cell.FixedHeight = 0;
cell.CellEvent = new BottomFix(table);
// such prepared cell goes to top level table, second row, left column
```